# Mezzanine + Cartridge 'Cart' instance needs to have a primary key value

Tags: django, mezzanine, cartridge

Good afternoon.
I just installed the cartridge to see its capabilities and got an error. Please help me solve this.

https://pastebin.com/tNuMbbQm

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/tNuMbbQm
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Made changes to the code as in the picture and it worked! I'm happy!